# Building .c file to create driver won't work following basic example

Tags: c, windows, makefile, driver, wdk

I'm following this basic example how to create a system driver:

http://sriramk.com/blog/2007/09/world-windows-driver-from-scratch.html

When I do the build I get the following (above the BUILD: lines):

```
0>XmlLog::File::CopyXslFile(): Unable to copy the XML style sheet C:\WinDDK\\7600.16385.1\\bin\\x86\\build.xsl => \build.xsl. Error: 0x000000002

0>SetFileAttributeW(.\build.xsl) failed. Error: 0x000000002
```

and it says 0 files compiled.

I navigated to that path (`C:\WinDDK\\7600.16385.1\\bin\\x86\\`) and I don't have a `build.xsl` file there.......?

I am on windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [VisualDDK](http://visualddk.sysprogs.org). It integrates nicely with VS2k10 and alleviates all the burdens regarding building of a device driver.